# Copy files from foobar playlist to other location

Tags: playlists, foobar2000

I have compiled a playlist in foobar audio player. My files lie in nested folders. There's a common root. Then there's a folder to distinguish the origin of the files (bought from amazon, iTunes, ripped from CD etc.) and eventually the typical hierarchy of artist and album.

When I drag the files from fb2k into a folder in explorer the hierarchy is flattened. The files are simply copied into one folder. A search on the internet says there's a tool `AmoK Playlist Copy` that allows for opening a `.fpl` playlist file and copy the audio files listed there into another directory maintaining the folder hierarchy. The latest version of that program dates back to 2011. I got it but was unable to open a `.fpl` playlist. Foobar has modified their file format. Historic playlist files stored in a folder `playlists-v1.3` can be read. Files from folder `playlists-v1.4`, however, cannot be read. The v1.3 files are far outdated.

I want to copy carefully selected files to a USB stick and want to maintain structure of folders.

How can I copy audio files from a playlist in foobar to a folder maintaining hierarchy of the subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the possibility to select some or even all files in a playlist, right click and select `File Operations` => `Copy to...`.

There's an input field for a pattern for the target file. That accepts operators and functions from foobar [documentation](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference). When the hierarchy of the folders is known and fixed one can work with the various functions.
A possible solution can look like: `$directory(%path%,3)/$directory(%path%,2)/%directory%/%filename%`.

That solution got support from foobar [forum](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,73043.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have all your files in

C:\music

And you want to copy it to your usb in

E:

and preserve the folder structure. Go to:

Foobar > playlist > select all the files that you want to copy > right click > File operations > Copy to > ...

Then this window will open:

[File Operations Setup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02JVc.jpg)

Now in that window:

Operation: Copy

Destination: E:\

File name: $replace(%path%,C:\music\,,%filename_ext%,)%filename%

Now check in the preview, if its correct. Then click 'Run'.

Explanation:

$replace(str,search1,replace1,search2,replace2)

ie.,

$replace(C:\music\mj\blackorwhite.flac,C:\music\,,blackorwhite.flac,)

1. Look for search2 in str and replace with replace2

Replace 'blackorwhite.flac' with '' in 'C:\music\mj\blackorwhite.flac'

Result: 'C:\music\mj\'

2. Look for search1 in the result we got above and replace with replace1

Replace 'C:\music\' with '' in 'C:\music\mj\'

Result: 'mj\'